# Rails 6 warning: Overwriting existing method <model_name>.fetched_state

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, arel

Rails 6.0.2.1
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]

my ArticleDir class has 2 scopes:

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: true).where(expired_on: nil) }
scope :fetched_state, -> { where(state: ArticleDir::FETCHED.to_s) }
```

and a function:

```
def article_engine_counts(keyword_reln = Keyword.active_keywords)
      joins(:keywords, :article_engine)
      .where(Keyword.contains(keyword_reln))
      .where(self.table[:active].eq(true))
      .group(:state, ArticleEngine.table[:name]).count
end
```

On running the function in rails console, I get:

> irb(main):108:0> ArticleDir.article_engine_counts(keyword)
>
> Creating scope :active. Overwriting existing method ArticleDir.active.
>
> Creating scope :fetched_state. Overwriting existing method ArticleDir.fetched_state.
>
> (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all,
>   `article_commons`.`state` AS article_commons_state, `sengines`.`name`
>   AS sengines_name FROM `article_commons` INNER JOIN
>   `directory_keywords` ON `directory_keywords`.`article_dir_id` =
>   `article_commons`.`id` INNER JOIN `keywords` ON `keywords`.`id` =
>   `directory_keywords`.`keyword_id` INNER JOIN `sengines` ON
>   `sengines`.`id` = `article_commons`.`sengine_id` AND `sengines`.`type`
>   = 'ArticleEngine' WHERE `article_commons`.`type` = 'ArticleDir' AND `keywords`.`id` IN (1217) AND `article_commons`.`active` = TRUE GROUP
>   BY `article_commons`.`state`, `sengines`.`name`
>
> => {["expired", "data..."]=>1, ["fetched", "data..."]=>83, ["sourced", " data..."]=>81}

I've seen one other reference to this issue:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31234
where it was suggested that the message related to overwriting a Kernel method.

I've checked the Kernel and no such methods exist on the Kernel in the first place to overwrite:

```
irb(main):002:0> Kernel.methods.grep(/active/)
=> []
irb(main):004:0> Kernel.methods.grep(/fetched_state/)
=> []
```

I am assuming that the message means what it seems to imply - arel / rails is somehow overwriting those two scopes on the model.

If so, why? and what do I do about it?

Answer (score 7):

This can happen when you have something such as an enum that add scopes to the model.

If, in your model, you had an enum with `:active` as one of the values, e.g.:

```
enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
```

to go along with your explicit scope, you would see this warning.